# Make android copy all from "_next" asset folder via aaptOptions

Tags: android, build.gradle

I recently discovered that android will ignore asset folders that start with `_` and that `aaptOptions { ignoreAssetsPattern }` can be used to overwrite this.

I googled around and found examples like this

```
aaptOptions {
  ignoreAssetsPattern '!.svg:!.woff:!.jpg:!*.scc:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~'
}
```

Which I assume do this for individual files? But I wanted to clarify if it is possible to include all files in `_next` asset folder as opposed to specifying each individual file?

If not, could you clarify what the difference between `!.svg` and `!*.scc` is and what `!*~` means at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ignoreAssetsPattern is only documented in the [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6d2c0e5/tools/aapt2/Files.h#88), there is only a default value if you use the build-tools to compile yourself with the option `--ignore-asset`, and the default pattern for that is:

```
!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~
```

The rules for the format are the following:

```
* Patterns syntax:
 * - Delimiter is :
 * - Entry can start with the flag ! to avoid printing a warning
 *   about the file being ignored.
 * - Entry can have the flag "<dir>" to match only directories
 *   or <file> to match only files. Default is to match both.
 * - Entry can be a simplified glob "<prefix>*" or "*<suffix>"
 *   where prefix/suffix must have at least 1 character (so that
 *   we don't match a '*' catch-all pattern.)
 * - The special filenames "." and ".." are always ignored.
 * - Otherwise the full string is matched.
 * - match is not case-sensitive.
```

So to answer all your questions, the difference between `!.svg` and `!*.scc` is that, the first one, will ignore the asset pattern for files or folders named ".svg", however, the second one, will ignore the asset pattern for all files or folders that have the .scc extension, what `!*~` means is to ignore all the files or folders that have the symbol ~ at the end

The proper config for your case will be:

```
aaptOptions {
  ignoreAssetsPattern '!_*'
}
```

So it will ignore the asset pattern for all files and folders starting with "_"